is there any way to make a textinput handle right to left languges?
basically title. after I halign the text to the right, how do I make the text go from right to left (the character that is typed after the last character should be to its left) instead of it being from left to right
or, at least for the cursor to move to the left when a character is typed

Add dir="rtl" attribute.

Do you mean <input type="text"> or <textarea>?

That answer is for HTML. for a TextInput usebase_direction: "rtl".

The supposed duplicate answer concerns HTML. The OP asks about a kivy TextInput widget. This is not a duplicate of that question. The answer is to use base_direction: "rtl".
